# Android: Getting date using day of the year number

Tags: android, datetime

How can I create a `Date` from an integer representing the day of the year?

Comment: Please don't just reference another question as your question, especially one that's closed and irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the day of year in the Calendar object, then you can get the Date object from it:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();// just make sure it's the right year
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```